# Show that there exists a matrix $A$ such that $R_a(x)=Ax$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

Let $a(\neq 0)\in \mathbb R^n$. Let us define the reflection operator $R_a=x-2\frac{x.a}{a.a}a$. Show that there exists a matrix $A$ such that $R_a(x)=Ax$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and prove that $\det A=-1$.

**My try**:
I chose the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^n$ as $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$. Then I took $R_a(e_i)$, expressed it in terms of $e_i$ and got the matrix $A$.

My questions are twofold:

1. Is there any anlternate way to find the matrix $A$.
2. How to find $\det A$. I find that it is easy to calculate $\det A$ for $n=2,3$ but what is the way out for higher dimensions? Can someone please help me out?

Comment: There is a mistake: it should be $R_a = x - 2 \frac{x \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a$ (note the $2$). As stated the determinant of $R_a$ is zero because $R_a(a) = a - a = 0$, and at any rate doesn't look like a reflection (it's instead the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the span of $a$).

Comment: @KeeleyHoek; you are right buddy!, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one way to do this is without explicitly finding the matrix at all! I think this is probably the most elegant: note that linear maps are in correspondence with with matrix operators, so all you need to do is check that $R_a$ is a linear map! And this is easy:
$$
R_a(\lambda x + y)
= \lambda x + y - 2\frac{(\lambda x + y) \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a
= \lambda x + y
- \lambda \cdot 2 \frac{x \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a
- 2\frac{y \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a
= \lambda R_a(x) + R_a(y).
$$

As for the determinant calculation, let's avoid matrices for that too. Recall that the determinant of a linear map (or equivalently a corresponding matrix) is the product of its generalized eigenvalues with multiplicity. So, we just need to find the eigenvalues of $R_a$.

First note that if $x$ any vector orthogonal to $a$ then $R_a(x) = x - 2\frac{x \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a = x$, so $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. Since the orthogonal complement of the span $S = \operatorname{span}(a)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n - 1$ dimensional, this means that we have found $(n - 1)$ eigenvalues which are all $1$. On the other hand the vector $a$ is not in the orthogonal complement $S^\perp$, and we have $R_a(a) = a - 2\frac{a \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a = -a$, so $a$ is an also an eigenvector, this time with eigenvalue $-1$!

Thus we have (without doing any matrix calculations) pinned down the  $n$ generalized eigenvalues of $R_a$: they are all $1$, except for a single $-1$. Thus
$$
\det(R_a) = \underbrace{1 \cdot 1}_{\text{$n-1$ times}} \cdot (-1) = -1,
$$
as desired.

---

As asked in comments: If we want to compute the $n \times n$ matrix which explicitly represents the action of $R_a$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ the recipe is just that it will have $i$th column equal to $R_a(e_i)$, where $\{e_i\}$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is arbitrary (let's write $a = \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j e_j$) then this is perhaps little bit yuck:
$$
R_a(e_i)
= e_i - 2\frac{e_i \cdot a}{a \cdot a} a
= e_i - 2\frac{a_i}{a \cdot a} \sum_{j = 1}^n a_j e_j.
$$
So in general this is going to look like:
$$
[R_a]_{\{e_j\}} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 - 2\frac{a_1^2}{a \cdot a}
&
 - 2\frac{a_1 a_2}{a \cdot a}
&
\cdots
&
 -2 \frac{a_1 a_n}{a \cdot a}
\\
 - 2\frac{a_1 a_2}{a \cdot a}
&
1 - 2\frac{a_2^2}{a \cdot a}
&
\cdots
&
 - 2\frac{a_2 a_n}{a \cdot a}
\\
 -2 \frac{a_1 a_3}{a \cdot a}
&
 - 2\frac{a_2 a_3}{a \cdot a}
&
\cdots
&
 - 2\frac{a_3 a_n}{a \cdot a}
\\
\vdots
&
\vdots
&
\ddots
&
\vdots
\\
- 2\frac{a_1 a_n}{a \cdot a}
&
- 2\frac{a_2 a_n}{a \cdot a}
&
\cdots
&
1 - 2\frac{a_n^2}{a \cdot a}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Your idea is very elegant, i have one question, how do we find the matrix A asily since the question explicitly asks us to determine it

Comment: @Math_Freak Is my edit along the lines of what you mean?

Comment: Yes thats right, I was askingg can we do it more elegantly ? Also wont there be a 2 in the matrix entries

Comment: @Math_Freak Thanks! And no, for general $a$ the best we can do is note that the $i$th diagonal entry is equal to a sum of $a_j^2$ for all $j$, where we put a minus sign for $i=j$.

Comment: Of course if we chose a different basis we could make this look like reflection about an axis (equivalently, the matrix is always diagonalizable, as we showed in the first part.)

Comment: One more question, can you please explain how do you get n-1 eigenvalues as 1, I dont understand that orthogonal part, will you pls elaborate, why is the orthogonal complement of span(a) n-1 dimensional

Comment: It's just that the orthogonal complement of $S$ is $n-1$ dimensional, and every element of $S^\perp$ is mapped to itself by $R_a$ (since the second term in the definition of $R_a$ is always zero for vectors orthogonal to $a$). Being mapped to yourself is the same as being an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes thats fine, thanks a lot,+1

Answer (score 1):

$$R_a(x) =x-2\tfrac{x^Ta}{a^Ta}a = \underbrace{(-2\tfrac{aa^T}{a^Ta})}_{=A}x$$

Then, by the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma)

$$ \det(-2\tfrac{aa^T}{a^Ta}) = \det()\det(1-2\tfrac{a^Ta}{a^Ta}) = \det(-1) = -1 $$

Comment: Its a great answer, really a nice trick,+1